# Shopify liquid get raw video url

Tags: shopify, liquid

In Shopify liquid, I am trying to render a video block from a section.

I have my own wrapped, so I simply want to get a raw URL; but nothing seems to work.
This won't return a proper url:

```
<video class="video" loop muted autoplay playsinline>
  <source src="{{ block.settings.video | file_url }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And this will create a whole video HTML element, that I don't want:

```
{{ block.settings.video | media_tag }}
```

Here is the schema for this field:

```
  {
    "name": "Video",
    "type": "video",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "video",
        "id": "video",
        "label": "Video"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Does someone know how can I get an url only?

Thanks,

Comment: Try like this to get the video URL : `block.settings.video.source.url`

Comment: @Onkar Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you please add the schema code also for better understanding?

Comment: Sure. Added. But it's a simple video input field. It should be appearing in their documentation...

Comment: `block.settings.video.sources[0].url` inside the block loop

Answer (score 4):

Okay, here you can see the `video` input type into Shopify documentation [Link](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/settings/input-settings#video)
[image]
[image]

You can see it returns the video object or null if no video is selected.

In [video object](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#video) the following data is associated:
[image]

Here into [video sources](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#video_source)
[image]

You can see the URL params to return the URL, so you need to get this URL like, sources return array of URL type so access specific URL like this

```
{{block.settings.video.sources[0].url}}
```

Comment: thanks! 

But, im my case, this is what did the job:
{{block.settings.video.sources[1].url}}

Because [0] was the url for a .m3u8 file, [1] is for the .mp4

Comment: @LucasPaiano I am not sure but I think every hosted video is ultimately a `mp4` format video. in my case I use this code - `{% assign video = block.settings.hosted_video.sources | where: 'format', 'mp4' | first %}`

Answer (score 0):

Also you can create a section with video picker

```js
{% schema %}{
  "name": "Video",
  "class": "video-section",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "video",
      "id": "video",
      "label": "A Shopify-hosted video"
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "Video"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

```html
{% if section.settings.video != blank %}
      <video src="{{section.settings.video.sources[1].url}}" loop muted playsinline autoplay></video>
    {% endif %}
```